# How to detect changes in custom types in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am working on custom types in sqlalchemy columns using `TypeDecorator`. I'm storing my data in `JSONB` inside Postgres DB, but in code I am serializing and deserializing it in a data class. But when I change any field of that data class, it didn't detect changes on that column. How can I achieve this in sqlalchemy.

**dataclass :**

```py
@dataclass
class ConfigFlags(DataClassJsonMixin):
    abc: bool = True
```

**custom type def :**

```py
class ConfigFlagType(types.TypeDecorator):

    """Type for config flags."""

    impl = JSONB

    def process_result_value(  # noqa: ANN201
        self,
        value: Optional[dict],
        dialect,  # noqa: ANN001
    ):
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            msg = "Value must be a dictionary"
            raise ValueError(msg)  # noqa: TRY004

        return ConfigFlags.from_dict(value)

    def process_bind_param(  # noqa: ANN201
        self,
        value: Optional[ConfigFlags],
        dialect,  # noqa: ANN001
    ):
        if not isinstance(value, ConfigFlags):
            msg = "Value must be a ConfigFlags"
            raise ValueError(msg)  # noqa: TRY004
        return value.to_dict()
```

**db model :**

```py
class ConvHistories(CBase):

    """conv_histories model."""

    __tablename__ = "test"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    config_flags: ConfigFlags = Column(
        ConfigFlagType,
    )

   def find_one(self, conv_id: int) -> "ConvHistories":
        return self.query.filter(  
            ConvHistories.id == conv_id,
        ).first()
```

```py
res = ConvHistories(session=session).find_one(conv_id=3)

if res.config_flags:
    res.config_flags.abc = False


session.add(res)
session.commit()
```

But it didn't detect changes in `config_flags` column.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [SqlAlchemy JSON docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) (which also apply to JSONB):

> The JSON type, when used with the SQLAlchemy ORM, does not detect in-place mutations to the structure. In order to detect these, the sqlalchemy.ext.mutable extension must be used, most typically using the MutableDict class. This extension will allow “in-place” changes to the datastructure to produce events which will be detected by the unit of work. See the example at HSTORE for a simple example involving a dictionary.

So, if you had a simple column, you'd wrap it like this:

```
config_flags = Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(JSONB))
```

In your case it's a bit more involved because you have a special wrapper class, but you still need to use the same mechanism.

More sample code + very good explanation can be found in this blog post [Beware of JSON fields in SQLAlchemy](https://amercader.net/blog/beware-of-json-fields-in-sqlalchemy/)

As simpler, but probably less efficient alternative to using the mutation tracking of MutableDict, you may also be able to, whenever you modify a config_flag, first make a deep copy and then add it back:

```
if res.config_flags:
   res.config_flags = copy.deepcopy(res.config_flags)
   res.config_flags.abc = False

   session.add(res)
   session.commit()
```